# I am wiring up a ceiling fan in my house built in 1973, how do I hook it up with 3 black, 3 white, and 3 ground present in fixture outlet?

Tags: electrical

I do know 1 set is hot from breaker box, 1 set is feeding a separate light in the same room, and the other set goes to the light/fan switch on the wall. When I tie all the same colors together it trips breaker when I flip switch to on for the ceiling fan. I want to keep the separate light working because I use it frequently. Any suggestions how to wire this up?

No aluminum wires present. All 3 wire copper lines in house.

Comment: if just used a phase tester

Answer (score 3):

How to wire it up - **the same way it was wired to the last thing...**

Too late, you've already lost that information, evidently. *Next time,* only disconnect the fixture, and don't touch any other wires in the box. And take a "before" picture for reference, too.

You appear to have a switch loop, so wiring all same colors together is **expected to trip the breaker** when you cause a dead short by flipping the switch, which is connected to black and white on its cable.

So you have to figure out which cable is which, and connect white on the switch cable to the other cables blacks, and black on the switch cable to the fixture black. The switch loop white should be marked with red or black tape, but often is not. You should do that, to indicate that it's not neutral due to the switch loop.

A multimeter would be helpful to find which cable has a connection between black and white only when the switch is on. That's your switch loop cable.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the breaker off.

The wires/cable to switch is a switch loop.  It uses the white and black as hot/live wire which creates a short when you connect all the whites together.

Place some black tape on the white wire going to the switch.

Connect the white switch wire to the two black wires from the ceiling box.

The black wire from the switch connects to the fan/light's black wire.

The white wire from the fan/light connects to the other two white wires.

Connect all the grounds together and to the box(if metal).

Turn the breaker back on.